# Strange Matlab error: "??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals"

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a function `func` that returns a vector `a`. I usually plot a and then perform further analysis on it. I have a certain scenario when once I try to plot a, I get a "`??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals`" error. Take a look at the following piece of code to see the vector's behavior:

```
K>> a

a =
    5.7047    6.3529    6.4826    5.5750    4.1488    5.8343    5.3157    5.4454    

K>> plot(a)
??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

K>> for i=1:length(a); b(i) = a(i); end;
K>> b

b =
    5.7047    6.3529    6.4826    5.5750    4.1488    5.8343    5.3157    5.4454    

K>> plot(b)
??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

The scenario where this happens is when I call function `func` from within another function (call it `outer_func`), and return the result directly as `outer_func`'s result. When debugging inside `outer_func`, I can plot a properly, but outside the scope of `outer_func`, its result has the above behavior.

What can cause this? Where do I start from?

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for [the generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you, somewhere inside your function, have a line like this:

```
plot = something
```

In this case, plot is considered an array inside the function, and your error might occur.

As an aside: you could replace the loop by `b=a`.