# Why is my script erroring with "Error:Index exceeds matrix dimensions"?

Tags: matlab

I made this script:

```
disp('Answer>>There are 25 prime numbers exist between 1-100')
x=isprime(1:100);
sum(x)
```

For some reason, it runs just once. For example, this script has the file name "question4", so when I type it in the main command, it prints: "There are.... ans=25" - which is perfect! but when I type again "question4", I get this error:

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
Error in question4 (line 3)
sum(x)
```

Any reason why?

Comment: Are you defining `sum` as a variable somewhere later?  Before the next run (assuming it is a script and not a function) type `which sum` at the command prompt.

Comment: As I wrote it's just a script. I made it to answer the question "How many prime numbers there are between 1to100", I guess my code is right, so when I run the script(by typing the file name of the script) in the command window once it prints the answer and when I try to run it again it gives me this error

Comment: the sum is a variable. I don't use it again somewhere later, this is the whole script.

Comment: Try adding `clear sum` to the top of your script.

Comment: Do not use any variable names, which overwrite function names e.g. `sum`

Comment: Thanks! it works when I add the clear sum.

Comment: OK.  Seeing as I guessed it, I'll turn it into an answer. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals, generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol)

Comment: @Shai The solution is certainly the same, but I think the error message Dennis' question is caused by indexing with non-scalar values. I think his QA _should_ cover this error, so I made a comment on his question that he might want to expand the scope of the QA.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful not to use `sum` or any other built-in function name as a variable.  To see if you are using it as a variable, check with the following:

```
>> which sum
sum is a variable.
```

If your output looks like the above, the variable `sum` is preventing the built-in `sum` function from being called as intended.  Try `clear sum` and make sure you are not assigning `sum` anywhere in your script.