# "index must be a positive integer or logical" error

Tags: matlab, runtime-error

When I try running a code I have in `MATLAB`, I get the following error:

```
Attempted to access labels(146.864,226.509); index must be a positive
integer or logical.

Error in abc (line 11)
    l(y(i),x(i))=1;
```

The points are set to be chosen interactively. But, is it the points that should be an `integer`? I tried casting the points `y(i), x(i)` to `int8`, but didn't work. Or, maybe I'm using it wrong?

How can I solve the error above?

Thanks.

Comment: can you not just round the values?

Comment: Please post the code that gives the error. Not just the error code

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Integer" in this context means that they should not have any decimal fraction, it does not refer to the type.

```
l(round(y(i)),round(x(i))=1
```

should work.

In addition, you may want to check that rounding does not lead to out-of-bounds value of your array `l`, i.e.

```
y = max(min(round(y),1),size(l,1);
```

N.B.: `l` is not a particularly good name for a variable.