# Elitism in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

How do i implement elitism in matlab? For example, i run a program and after each run, a value is save in a variable say a and after completing all the runs, say 6 runs i have the `a` as follows

```
a = [7, 5, 4, 3, 6, 8];
```

how can i apply elitism on `a` to end of having the content of `a` as `a = [7, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3];`

That is when i scan through `a`, i will replace the bigger number with the small one i encounter. From the example, after scanning through `a`, `5<7`, so i keep `5`, `4<5`, so i keep `4`, `3<4`, so i keep `3`, `3<6`, so i replace `6` with `3`, and again `3< 8`, so i replace `8` with `3` to end of having the `a` as `a = [7, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3];`

how do u do this in Matlab.

Attempt

I said,

```
if a(i)< a(i+1)
a(i+1) = a(i);
end

plot(a);
```

so that i can have a graph that decents smoothly.

but i keep having the following error:

`'Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.'`

Any idea how i can do this correctly.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for a [generic approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722) to deal with this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this should work for all cases:

```
b = [a(1), arrayfun(@(n) min(a(1:n)), 2:length(a))]

a =
     7     4     3     6     5     2     5
b =
     7     4     3     3     3     2     2
```

**For info:**

Your initial thought was correct, but you forgot to put the `if` inside a loop. You could have done:

```
for ii = 1:length(a)-1
   if a(ii)< a(ii+1)
      a(ii+1) = a(ii);
   end
end
```

The reason why you got the error was because you probably hadn't defined `i`, thus MATLAB interpreted it as the imaginary unit (`sqrt(-1)`). That's also the reason why I used `ii` instead of `i` in the loop, to avoid such errors.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. My initial thoughts were right. I just put the if statement in a loop as you suggested and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited** to work with local minima:

```
a = [7, 5, 4, 3, 6, 8];
[y, i] = findpeaks(-a, 'npeaks', 1) ;
a(i:end)=-y;
plot(a)
```

The plot:

[image: a plotted]

Comment: If the vector is `[7 4 3 6 2 8]` this wouldn't work.

Comment: doesn't work for all cases. `a = [ 7 4 5 3 6 8 ]` as an example.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to [Robert P.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21293824/2586922) without `arrayfun`:

```
min(triu(repmat(a(:),1,numel(a))) + tril(NaN(numel(a)),-1))
```

Comment: +1, clever... I actually had to test it in MATLAB to see the logic =P Note that this will take up a lot of memory if the vector is long.

Comment: @RobertP. Thanks. Yes, it uses a lot of memory to build he matrix