# Getting the error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals" despite the workspace indicating my varirable all = 1

Tags: matlab

I am getting this error in MatLab when trying to fill in an array.  MatLab is saying that the assignment `B(j, 1) = z(z-counter)` contains a negative or non integer value.  However when I look at the variables values in the workspace after trying to execute the code.
`j =1, counter =1, z =1`

```
for j= 1:1:totalSizeOfMatrix
    if( j <= totalNumberInBottom)
        if( mod(j, lengthOfBottomRow) == 1)
            counter= counter +1;
        end
        z = mod(j,lengthOfBottomRow);
        B(j,1) = z(z-counter);
    end
    if( j > totalNumberInBottom && j <= totalNumberNotInTop)
        if( mod(j, lengthOfSecondRow) == 1)
            counter= counter +1;
        end
        z = mod(j,lengthOfSecondRow);
        B(j,1) = z(z-counter);
    end
    if( j > totalNumberInBottom)
        if( mod(j, lengthOfTopRow) == 1)
            counter= counter +1;
        end
        z = mod(j,lengthOfTopRow);
        B(j,1) = z(z-counter);
    end
end
```

Comment: MATALB index starts at 1. Therefore, z(0) is invalid.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for a [generic approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722) to deal with this error.

Answer (score 1):

If `z = 1` and `counter = 1`, then `z - counter` is zero.

Therefore, `z(z-counter)` is trying to access `z(0)`, which is an error.