# map a matrix with another matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a question to the mapping of a matrix with another matrix which contains only 1 and 0. 
Here an example of my problem: `A` is the matrix with doubles

```
A = [ 1 4 3;
      2 3 4; 
      4 3 1; 
      4 5 5; 
      1 2 1];
```

B is a matrix with ones and zeros:

```
B = [ 0 0 0;
      0 0 0;
      1 1 1;
      1 1 1;
      0 0 0];
```

I want to achieve a matrix `C` which is the result of `A` mapped by `B`, just like that:

```
C = [ 0 0 0;
      0 0 0;
      4 3 1;
      4 5 5;
      0 0 0];
```

I tried `B` as a logical array and as a matrix. Both lead to the same error:

> "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for a [generic approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722) to deal with this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just multiply A and B element-wise:

```
C = A.*B
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Dan's solution, but this would be another way:

```
C = zeros(size(A));
C(B==1) = A(B==1);
```

Comment: this approach is also useful, especially for cells where the above operations do not work. Thank you!