# assign strings into matrix elements

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I use MATLAB and I have to make the following pairing:

I have an array with integers:

```
A = [1 0 1 0 1]
```

and an array of the same dimension, with strings:

```
B = ['a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e']
```

I need to create a string array, `C`, where for every element of matrix `A` that is `0` the corresponding element of matrix `C` is blank (`''`) but for every element of matrix `A` that is `1`, the corresponding element of matrix `C` is equal with the corresponding element of `B`.

i.e. the array `C` would be :

```
C = ['a' '' 'c' '' 'e']
```

Comment: Repeated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043110/map-a-matrix-with-another-matrix/22043212#22043212

Comment: Do you want `C = ['a' '' 'c' '' 'e']` (which is the same as `C='ace'`), or do you want `C = {'a' '' 'c' '' 'e'}`?

Comment: @tashuhka, do you want to mark this as a duplicate question? I'm not sure it is, since this is for strings and that qeustion was for integers.

Comment: @patrickvacek. You have more experience than me to know what can be considered duplicate and what cannot. I just saw that logical indexing was partially covered in the mentioned link.

Comment: i want the second option, i.e. C = {'a' '' 'c' '' 'e'}

Comment: @tashuhka, no problem! They are similar, but I think they are different enough to exist independently. They could be generalized into one solution, but probably not if the empty strings need to be represented.

Comment: @patrickvacek. I agree :)

Answer (score 3):

If you define `B` as a `cell` array makes more sense:

```
B = {'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e'}
```

then assign empties like so:

```
>> B(A==0) = {''}
B = 
   'a'    ''    'c'    ''    'e'
```

Comment: how can i convert matrix B=['a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e'] to cell B1={'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e'}

Comment: @user3270686: Like this: `B = 'some test string'; B = num2cell(B)`

Answer (score 1):

Use logical indexing

```
C = B( A == 1 )
```

Comment: blanks are omitted ! C=['a' 'c' 'e']