# R: Map a matrix with another matrix in r

Tags: r, matrix

I found a same question in [map a matrix with another matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043110/map-a-matrix-with-another-matrix). But, that is in Matlab. If I want to map a matrix with another matrix in R, How can I easily get without using a loop. For example, I have following matrices,

```
A = [ 1 4 3
      2 3 4 
      4 3 1 
      4 5 5 
      1 2 1]

 B = [3 3 2
      2 0 1
      1 1 5
      4 1 3
      5 2 0]
```

My mapping should be as given bellow;

```
  R = [1 4 3
      2 3 4
      4 3 5
      4 1 3
      5 2 0]
```

The result R will take the values from A starting from [1,1] to [3,2]. Then remaining values are from B starting from [3,3] to [5,3].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as:

```
R <- t(A)
R[9:15] <- t(B)[9:15]
t(R)
```

> ```
>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
> [1,]    1    4    3
> [2,]    2    3    4
> [3,]    4    3    5
> [4,]    4    1    3
> [5,]    5    2    0
> ```

#### Sample data

```
A <- matrix(c(1,4,3,2,3,4,4,3,1,4,5,5,1,2,1), nrow = 5, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
B <- matrix(c(3,3,2,2,0,1,1,1,5,4,1,3,5,2,0), nrow = 5, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: It's working. I am wondering how important the transpose here. I tried your method without doing transpose. It was wrong. Nice solution @DJack.

Answer (score 0):

A little different to Djack's approach, I used `matrix` with a `byrow = T`, and indexed the original matrices:

```
matrix(c(t(A)[1:8], t(B)[9:15]), byrow = T, ncol = 3)
```

Comment: Interesting approach but it should be `matrix(c(t(A)[1:8], t(B)[9:15]), byrow = T, ncol = 3)`.