# Get the eigen vector correspoinding to the ith largest eigen value

Tags: matlab, for-loop, pca, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I have tried this code for my assignments, but I am getting error of type

```
??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

This is my code:

```
for i = 5:200
    eigvecm = eigvecm(:, end:-1:end-(int8(i)-1));
end
```

Please point me out how to get this done?

Comment: Wow! What are you doing? Using "i" as iterator and then changing "eigvecm" in the loop itself and then using "end" as the indexing.

Comment: in **eigvecm=eigvecm(:,`end:-1:end-(int8(i)-1)`)** what do you want to do here?

Comment: I am trying to get maximum of 'i' column from eigvecm matrix, It works fine if I use number like 5 etc,..but not working when i use 'i' as variable.

Comment: here what exactly happen is, it will give you out the i number of eigenvector corresponding to first ith maximum eigenvalue.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for a [generic approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722) to deal with this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds very much like `end-(int8(i)-1)` ends up reaching zero or below. Check what is the value of `i` when you get the error and compare this to how many columns `eigvecm` has.

BTW if you want the eigen vecotr corresponding to the ith largest eigen value how about this:

```
[vec, val] = eig(M);
[~, ind] = sort(diag(val), 'descend');
```

`ind(i)` is the column number for the ith largest eigen value. So to find the corresponding eigen vector:

```
vec_i = vec(:, ind(i));
```

Comment: thank you for your amazing answer, I got the concept.

Comment: @cybertrone so what was wrong though? Was `i` getting larger than the number of columns of `eigvecm`?

Comment: yes , you were right,I was applying this code for pca.

Comment: You might consider to use the SVD functions to do PCA. Singular values usually are returned sorted from largest to smallest.