# Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals using min

Tags: matlab, struct, min, subscript

```
for control=1:7
    name=strcat('tau: ', num2str(TD(control)),'   PLD: ', num2str(PLD(control)));
    fprintf('Control: %i/7\n', control)
    Maps(control) = struct('GradOFF', [], 'GradON', []);
    for lin=1:size(data(subject).perf_w_off,1)
        fprintf('Lin: %i/64\n', lin);
        for col=1:size(data(subject).perf_w_off,2)
            [x1, fval, exitflag, output] = fminunc(...)
            Maps(control).GradOFF(lin,col) = abs(x1(2));
            [x2, fval, exitflag, output] = fminunc(...)
            Maps(control).GradON(lin,col) = abs(x2(2));
        end
    end

    min1 = min(min(Maps(control).GradOFF));
    min2 = min(min(Maps(control).GradON));
    min = min([min1, min2]);
    max1 = max(max(Maps(control).GradOFF));
    max2 = max(max(Maps(control).GradON));
    max = max([max1, max2]);

    figure(map1);

    subplot(2,7,control)
    image1 = mat2gray(Maps(control).GradOFF,[min, max]);
    imshow(image1,[]);
    title(strcat(name, ' Grad Off'))

    subplot(2,7, control+7)
    image2 = mat2gray(Maps(control).GradON,[min, max]);
    imshow(image2,[]);
    title(strcat(name, ' Grad On'))
end
```

Nothing seems to go wrong with this code. The first loop (the one over control) is doing fine. However when going through the loop again (control = 2), then an error message appears when doing `min1 = min(min(Maps(control).GradOFF))`. It says:

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

but when I'm doing `mean(mean(Maps(control).GradOFF))` it is working. Could someone tell me what could go possibly wrong with `min` that won't with `mean`?

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for a [generic approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722) to deal with this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining a variable `min` in this line:

```
min = min([min1, min2]);
```

Once you have done that, `min1 = min(min(Maps(control).GradOFF));` is being interpreted as a reference to the variable `min`, not the function, hence the error on the second time around.  Rename that variable so it's not got the same name as the function.  The same goes for `max = max([max1, max2]);` which will give you the same problem if you don't correct it.

Comment: So stupid! Thank you for your help. I went trough these lines a hundred times and never saw that mistake.