# Why this is showing me `Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals` in Matlab ??

Tags: matlab, variables

Why this portion of code is still showing me an error of kind `Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals` the indices are `uint8` so real positive integers ???

```
    t = uint8( t_lbls(i) );
    te = uint8( test_lbls(e) ); 
    mat2conf(t,te) = mat2conf( t,te )+ 1;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals, generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol)

Comment: I saw that, it did not solve my problem

Comment: At the request of @thewaywewalk I have made the point more clear that 0 is also not a valid index value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you may have indices that are 0.  Try offsetting by 1.  You will also need to cast to `double` because if you add 1 to 255, you will not get 256.  It will cap off to 255 as you have casted your arrays to `uint8`.  The purpose of you casting to `uint8` is unclear to me, but I will assume that this step is necessary.  As such, you simply have to add the following two lines.

```
t = uint8( t_lbls(i) );
te = uint8( test_lbls(e) ); 
t = double(t) + 1; % Cast and offset t
te = double(te) + 1; % Cast and offset te
mat2conf(t,te) = mat2conf( t,te )+ 1;
```

Comment: I think `t,te` should be `positive integers` not `doubles` ? (I have tried your code, same error )

Comment: Are any of your indexes 0?  If that's the case, you need to offset by 1.

Comment: that's right :) and that is the problem , one of the offset is 0 thank you

Comment: Very welcome!  I modified my post above.  Let me know if that works.