# Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals while Registering Multimodal 3-D Medical Images

Tags: matlab

I got this error while trying to do the sample on [Registering Multimodal 3-D Medical Images](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/registering-multimodal-3-d-medical-images.html). the sample files are at [this URL](http://www.insight-journal.org/rire/download_training_data.php).
Here are what commands I used:

```
fixedHeader  = helperReadHeaderRIRE('header.ascii'); // at training_001/mr_T1 folder
movingHeader = helperReadHeaderRIRE('header.ascii'); // at training_001/ct folder
fixedVolume  = multibandread('image.bin',...
                            [fixedHeader.Rows, fixedHeader.Columns, fixedHeader.Slices],...
                            'int16=>single', 0, 'bsq', 'ieee-be' );
                            // at training_001/mr_T1 folder
movingVolume = multibandread('image.bin',...
                            [movingHeader.Rows, movingHeader.Columns, movingHeader.Slices],...
                            'int16=>single', 0, 'bsq', 'ieee-be' );
                            // at training_001/ct folder
helperVolumeRegistration(fixedVolume,movingVolume);
centerFixed = size(fixedVolume)/2;
centerMoving = size(movingVolume)/2;
figure, title('Unregistered Axial slice');
imshowpair(movingVolume(:,:,centerMoving(3)), fixedVolume(:,:,centerFixed(3)));
```

and I get the error.
I use MATLAB 2014a version.

Comment: For the [generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722), see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20054047/983722).

Answer (score 1):

The cause probably is that the 3rd dimension of `fixedVolume` and/or `movingVolume` is an odd number so that dividing by 2 produces a non-integer (###.5). Such a fractional number can not be used as an index into an array, as you try to do on the last line. A possible fix is to round the result of the division:

```
centerFixed = round(size(fixedVolume)/2);
centerMoving = round(size(movingVolume)/2);
```