# Truncate audio file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio

I am trying to read a WAV file in MATLAB and truncate it to 1 sec.

Here is the code I am trying right now, taken from:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/596-truncating-wav-files

`[x,fs,k] = wavread(FileNames);
 Y = x(n:n+fs-1, :);`

This however gives me the following error:

`Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
 Error in Test (line 13)
     Y = x(n:n+fs-1, :);`

How can I fix this and how I can do the truncation?

Comment: Have you checked what is `n` and `fs`? What is the output of `n:n+fs-1`? Probably you could find the answer by yourself.

Comment: For the [generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722), see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20054047/983722).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `n` is at least 1. Also make sure it's not exceeding length of `x`. It can't be that hard. Just see the indices