# Matlab imfilter function implemenation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to write a function that implements imfilter function. but getting this error.

> ??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals

at this point

> s= size(img);

Find below the code snippet

```
s = size(img);
Ix = zeros(s);
Iy = zeros(s);
for i = 1:s
    for j = 1:s
        temp = img(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1) .* Gx;
        Ix(i,j) = sum(temp(:));
    end
end
```

Please is there anything Im doing wrong?

**EDITED CODE**

```
s = size(img);
Ix = zeros(s);
Iy = zeros(s);
for i = 2:s(1)-1
    for j = 2:s(2)-1
        temp = img(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1) .* Gx;
        Ix(i,j) = sum(temp(:));
    end
end
```

Comment: For the [generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722), see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20054047/983722).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it genuinely happens at the point of calling `s= size(img);`, then you probably have a variable `size` in your workspace which is shadowing the `size` function.

In addition, there are a couple of possible issues with your loop.  First, you can't use zero as in index in MATLAB.  Hence, when you have `i = 1, j = 1` at the start of your loop, you would expect the `temp` line to return the Subscript indices error.

the output of `size`, presuming `img` is a greyscale image, is going to be two numbers.  When you do `i = 1:s`, it will ignore the second one.  This is fine so long as your image is square but will not do what you expect if it isn't.

Finally, have a look at `conv2` for cases like this rather than creating a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But getting another error.
>> "Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles." I have edited the question to add the edited code

Comment: Exact as the error says - one of your variables is an integer, one is something other than an integer or a double (probably `Gx`).  Please read:  http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/debugging-code.html

Comment: Try casting your `img` variable to `double` before you go through the loop.