# Matlab - division of Array by a numerical values

Tags: matlab

I tired a simple MATLAB programming. u(j,i) is a Matrix in this case. But the code resulted in the following error.

Problem1 : 
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in Problem1 (line 73)
        u(j,i)= (psi(j,i+1)-psi(j,i-1))*0.25;

Kindly help to solve this.

Comment: are you sure `i-1` is always positive ?

Comment: I'm sorry. Now I understood my mistake. i has an initial value '1'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals, generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be willing to bet that the FOR-loop you wrapped around the statement in question runs i from 1 to whatever, which would cause you to try to calculate psi(j,2)-psi(j,0), which MATLAB is telling you is illegal.

Comment: yeah. I made that mistake. the value of i is from '0' to something