# iterate over a function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to iterate over a function in order to extract the discrete values of a symbolic function:

```
syms x;
y =  sinc(x);
x = -100:1:100;
for i = 1:length(x)
    t(i) = y(x(i));
end
```

but it gives me error:

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

if I use:

```
t(i) = y{i}(x);
```

it says that:

```
SYM objects do not allow nested indexing. Assign intermediate values to variables instead.
```

So how this can be done in matlab, it looks like the linear sampling from symbolic function is somewhat more complicated than expected, or is there a function for this that I'm missing here?

Comment: Related Q&A that may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol/20054048#20054048

Comment: Thanks but this is the thing that I want to do, you know that its not possible to index sym object in general right?

Comment: How about `y = @(x) sinc(x)` (but then neither `y` or `x` are symbolic, but maybe getting there)

Comment: or `t(i) = subs(y,'x',x(i));`. (but it doesn't like it for `x=0`)

Comment: I can give it 0 like     if (x(i) ~= 0)
        subs(y,'x',x(i));    else
        t(i) = NaN;
    right? so that would be the answer then(post as answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `y` variable is not a [symbolic function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-symbolic-functions.html), but a [symbolic expression](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-symbolic-numbers-variables-and-expressions.html). If you want to leave it a symbolic expression, you can do something like this:

```
syms x;
y = sinc(x);
x2 = -100:1:100;               % Don't overwrite your symbolic variable x
t = zeros(length(x2),1,'sym'); % Pre-allocate
for i = 1:length(x2)
    t(i) = subs(y,x,x2(i));
end
```

Or, more simply:

```
syms x;
y = sinc(x);
x2 = -100:1:100;
t = subs(y,x,x2);
```

You can also convert `y` to a [symbolic function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html):

```
syms x;
y(x) = sinc(x);
x2 = -100:1:100;
t = y(x2);
```

Note that in all cases you'll get divide-by-zero error because your `x2` vector includes `0`. This is because `sinc` is a numeric function that hasn't been overloaded for symbolic math.

Is there any reason you're not evaluating this numerically?:

```
y = @(x)sinc(x);
x = -100:1:100;
t = y(x);
```

If you really need a symbolic `sinc` function you can create your own vectorized version using MuPAD's [`piecewise`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/piecewise.html):

```
sinc_sym = @(x)subs(evalin(symengine,'piecewise([x~=0, sin(x)/x],[Otherwise, 1])'),'x',x);
```

Or:

```
sinc_sym = @(x)subs(evalin(symengine,'piecewise([x~=0, sin(pi*x)/(pi*x)],[Otherwise, 1])'),'x',x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've assigned `y` to a symbolic object, but it is not a function. You can evaluate it at each `x(i)` with [`subs`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html):

```
t(i) = subs(y,'x',x(i));
```

This has the additional issue that you get an error for `x=0`, but, as you  suggested, could set `t(i)` with an `if` statement, something like

```
 if (x(i) ~= 0)
   subs(y,'x',x(i));
 else 
   t(i) = NaN; % or = 1 (limit of sinc(x) as x -> 0)
 end
```