# for loop indices in matlab not running because "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to integrate a DE using Euler's method. I can get through the entire method once, but it will not reloop. I end up with the error of "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.", and I'm not sure why.

I already found: [Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals, generic solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) and tried those methods of troubleshooting, to no avail.

Here is my code. My apologies for the sloppiness of it:

```
clc 
clear

N(1) = 2.5; %1st gear
N(2) = 2.0; %2nd ^
N(3) = 1.0; %3rd ^

Diff = 2.3; %Final drive

u = 0.8;
fr = 0.015;
Rt = .303; %Tire radius in m
W = 13400; %Weight in N
rho = 1.25; %Air density in kg/m^3
A = 2.10; %Frontal alrea in m^2
Cd = 0.38; %Coeff of drag
L = 2.61; %Wheelbase in m
LH = 3.93; %L/H ratio
FR = 51.5; %F/R weight ratio
theta1 = 0; %Road incline
theta2 = 5; %Road incline
Ftmax = 3000;
m = W/9.81;

w = 0.001;
xdot = 0.001;

dbstop if error
% T = -(0.00108*w^2)+0.50143+111.77086 %Engine tq lookup

for i = 1:0.001:200 %Total time of 200 seconds in 0.001 second intervals
%        if i<.001
%        end
    T(i) = -(0.00108*w(i)^2)+0.50143*w(i)+111.77086; %Engine tq lookup

    Ft(i) = T(i)*N(1)*Diff/Rt; %Calculate tractive force

    if Ft>Ftmax   %Check for traction limit
        Ft = Ftmax;
    end

    xddot(i) = (1/m)*(Ft(i)/xdot(i)-W*u*(1+xdot(i)*3.6/160)-0.5*rho*Cd*A*xdot(i)^2-W*sin(theta1));% Using m/s for velocity
    xdot(i) = xddot(i)*0.001+xdot(i); %Velocity calculation
    w(i) = xdot(i)/Rt*N(1)*Diff; %Engine speed calculation
end
```

I have asked a few friends that code, and they have no idea either. Hopefuly someone here can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subscript indices aren't integers. So instead of:

```
for i = 1:0.001:200 %Total time of 200 seconds in 0.001 second intervals
```

You could try something like this:

```
for i = 1:200*1000 %Total time of 200 seconds in 1 millisecond intervals
```

---

Also, since you're working with vectors in the loop, you might want to allocate them ahead of time, so you could replace this:

```
w = 0.001;
xdot = 0.001;
```

With this:

```
steps = 200*1000; % You might also want to replace 200*1000 in the for-loop with 'steps'

T = zeros(1,steps);
Ft = zeros(1,steps);
xddot = zeros(1,steps);
xdot = zeros(1,steps);
w = zeros(1,steps);

w(1) = 0.001;
xdot(1) = 0.001;
```